# How can I get complete absolute URL for paperclip attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on JSON data, I want to display complete image url with localhost name
but I'm getting half item_image_url..

"item_image_url": "/system/images/item_images/000/000/001/original/images_%284%29.jpeg?1545807832"

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Pasta",
        "filename": "Burger.",
        "item_image_file_name": "images_(4).jpeg",
        "item_image_content_type": "image/jpeg",
        "item_image_file_size": 12944,
        "item_image_updated_at": "2018-12-26T07:03:52.284Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-12-26T07:03:52.355Z",
        "created_at": "2018-12-26T07:03:52.355Z",
        "item_image_url": "/system/images/item_images/000/000/001/original/images_%284%29.jpeg?1545807832"
    }
```

how can i get this complete ulr like this
 http://localhost:3000/system/images/item_images/000/000/001/original/images_%284%29.jpeg?1545807832

in controller

```
class V1::ImagesController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def index

         @images = Image.all


         render :json => @images.to_json(:methods => [:item_image_url])
    end

    def show
        image = Image.find(params[:id])
        render json: {status: 'success', data:image},status: :ok
    end


    def create
         image = Image.new(image_params)
        if  image.save
            render json: {status: 'success', data:image},status: :ok    
        else
            render json: {status: 'error', message:'image not saved', data:image.errors},status: :unprocessable_entity  
        end 
    end


    def destroy
        image = Image.find(params[:id])
        image.destory
        render json: {status: 'success', data:image},status: :ok    
    end

    private def image_params

        params.permit(:item_image_url,:title,:filename)

    end

end
```

in model

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord

    has_attached_file :item_image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :item_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/


    def item_image_url
        self.item_image.url(:original)
    end

end
```

Pleas need help..

Comment: I don't need any help.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/584#issuecomment-1985865), it is cleaner to use ActionController::Base.asset_host so it would result the helper:

```
  def add_host_prefix(url)
    URI.join(ActionController::Base.asset_host, url)
  end
```

This supposes you have  the following in every /config/environments/*environment*.rb file:

```
Appname::Application.configure do

  # ....

  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000' # Locally

  # ....

end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000' I'm add this code in  /config/environments/.rb but getting = undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Define constant `APP_URL` in `config/development.rb` as,

```
APP_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

For `test.rb` & `production.rb`, You have to set as per your domain environment set up.

And get it as,

```
def item_image_abs_url
    "#{APP_URL}#{item_image.url(:original)}"
end
```

Check following url you get in rails console,

```
image = Image.first
image.item_image.url
```

Comment: What url do you get by `item_image_abs_url` ?

Comment: has you say i add your code config/development.rb = APP_URL = 'http://localhost:3000' and also test.rb and production.rb def item_image_abs_url
    "#{APP_URL}item_image.url(:original)}"
end but noting working is in same condition has i show above json data..

Comment: check in rails console by @image.item_image_url and tell what string you get

Comment: for @image.item_image_url =                                                                    
 (undefined method `item_image_url' for nil:NilClass)..for image.item_image_url =                                                    (undefined method `item_image_url' for #<Image::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000055665ee042b8>)

Comment: for image = Image.first =<Image id: 1, title: "Pasta", filename: "Burger.", item_image_file_name: "images_(4).jpeg", item_image_content_type: "image/jpeg", item_image_file_size: 12944, item_image_updated_at: "2018-12-26 07:03:52", updated_at: "2018-12-26 07:03:52", created_at: "2018-12-26 07:03:52">

Comment: irb(main):001:0> image = Image.first
  Image Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "images".* FROM "images" ORDER BY "images"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Image id: 1, title: "Pancakes.", filename: "Pancakes.", item_image_file_name: "download_(5).jpeg", item_image_content_type: "image/jpeg", item_image_file_size: 13323, item_image_updated_at: "2018-12-26 11:08:53", updated_at: "2018-12-26 11:08:53", created_at: "2018-12-26 11:08:53">
irb(main):002:0> image.item_image.url
=> "/system/images/item_images/000/000/001/original/download_%285%29.jpeg?1545822533"
irb(main):003:0>  show same ans.

Comment: So add `APP_URL` in `developement.rb` restart console &  try in console `"#{APP_URL}#{image.item_image.url}"`

Answer (score 0):

As per the description mentioned in the post it seems like you haven't specified the asset host in specific environment file.

Appropriate way as defined in the above mentioned answer as well is to define asset hosts in the relevant config/environments/{environment} file:
where the environment mentioned in the above line signifies development.rb, production.rb and test.rb(others as well if you have defined a custom environment)

```
onfig.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

If you want to access it in views then use below mentioned code:

```
asset_url(model.attachment.url(:style))
```

If you want to access it rails console then use below mentioned code

```
helper.asset_url(model.attachment.url(:style))
```

If you want to use it in a model then use below mentioned code:

```
ApplicationController.helpers.asset_url(model.attachment.url(:style))
```

Hope it helps!!